# I can't open the terminal in Cinnamon

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I have Linux Mint 13 with Cinnamon installed, but I can't open a terminal using right click nor using <kbd>Ctlr</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> this is just an issue with Cinnamon, why is that happening?

Comment: I don't use mint or cinnamon, but you are aware that those sorts of actions depend upon the desktop environment and/or window manager and how they are configured?  Ie, they are not universal to linux.  So: are you sure that this is how you are supposed to open a terminal with cinnamon?  Or are you just assuming that based on something else you have used before?

Comment: @goldilocks i'm not a newbie, i used mint for a long time, then used ubuntu 12.04 then came back to mint, when you right click in cinnamon, you see an option "open in terminal" it does nothing on my laptop, and the shortcut isn't working, i think it's because an error while downloading cinnamon but not sure

Comment: @goldilocks and i haven't configured anything, it's just installed, all i did is use nomodeset in the boot option and download the required drivers that mint and ubuntu tell you to download when you first install them

Comment: Okay, just checking.

Comment: @Lynob It's better to post the solution as an actual *answer*. You can accept your own answer and it's clearer to future visitors that this question was actually answered.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan just did, actually that's what I do nowadays but this question is 4 years old, back then I didn't know that one can answer his own question and didn't bother revisiting it since then. I'm no longer using linux mint either so forgot about it.

Comment: No worries. Have an upvote! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[gnome terminal wasn't installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1048452?comments=all), i don't know if anyone is going to fix that, but i solved it by

`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

and i posted my solution on launchpad, I'm not going to delete this question. maybe someone else faces this problem.

Comment: Signed up to this stack to simply say thank you for not deleting this !

Comment: where do I type that in if i can't open terminal?

Comment: @acme64 search for `xterm` it must be installed on your system, if not, then go to `tty` by pressing  ctrl + alt + f1 and type it there https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty