# Terminal doesn't open in Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal

I'm using Linux Mint. When I click on terminal, it doesn't open (there is no response.)

How can I open it?  Below information may be useful:

> ```
> Kernel: 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Cinnamon 3.0.6
> ```

Distro: Linux Mint 18 Alex

I have tried what suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59867/i-cant-open-the-terminal-in-cinnamon), but it didn't solve the problem. It returns:

> ```
> gnome-terminal is already the newest version (3.18.3-linuxmint1)
> ```

EDIT: It is very odd, because I have created another account and in new account terminal can be opened.

Comment: Compare the shell initialization files between the two accounts. If the shell fails or exits while running e.g. `.bashrc`, it may prevent the terminal from starting.

Comment: How can I do that? @Kusalananda

Comment: How can I "Compare the shell initialization files between the two accounts."? @Kusalananda

Comment: Log into the account whose terminal works and look at the two sets of files and/or run a `diff` on them. The two sets of files being the shell initialization files on the two accounts.

Comment: where can I find "two sets of files"? @Kusalananda

Comment: Please help me. I don't know how to get rid of this problem @Kusalananda

Comment: On the account where the terminal does not open, the shell's initialization files (either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) may be broken somehow, or there may be some other configuration that is not correct. You never told us what you changed before this started happening (it does not happen by itself).  Until you have given more information and looked into the _possible_ issues that I have mentioned, I'm going to vote to close this question as "too broad".

Comment: I don't know what have I done which has made it not work. I have also searched alot, but I didn't find any useful thing @Kusalananda

Comment: There is no .bash_profile in .bash folder @Kusalananda

Comment: In your home folder, there will be a file called `.bash_profile` and/or another called `.bashrc` You view their contents from inside your home directory with `cat .bash_profile` or `cat .bashrc` Compare them for each user and see if there's anything different.

Comment: I can find .bashrc in the account in which terminal doesn't open, but there is no .bashrc in the other account @NasirRiley

Comment: Is there a `.bash_profile`?

Comment: No, there isn't @NasirRiley

Comment: Then I recommend what the others have suggested which is to rename your `.bashrc` file or comment out it's contents and see if that fixes the issue. Worst-case scenario, if you have root access, you can just wipe the account out and recreate it.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question, as it does not give any log contents or error messages that GNOME Terminal will have written.  Contrast better questions such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413880/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344617/ .

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have mentioned, things in your bash startup files (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`) could be causing your shell to exit instantly, which could be causing the terminal emulator to instantly close.

It working properly on another account without a `.bashrc` suggests that something in your `.bashrc` is causing this.

If this is the case, renaming your `.bashrc` file should allow you to open your terminal emulator. You can then try to isolate the error by removing parts of your `.bashrc` until it starts up normally, or you can try using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/).

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be an issue in a shell startup file, but it's a very real possibility. For example, the result of a botched edit.

Comment: I renamed bashrc but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @AlexanderFill try opening a TTY (I think a shortcut should be Ctrl+Alt+F2), and logging in to the account that isn't working, to see if bash is working there

Comment: When I opened TTY, how can I check if the bash is working ? @boxama

Comment: @AlexanderFill if you can sign in and the bash prompt appears without error, it is working. To test your terminal emulator try `DISPLAY=':0' gnome-terminal` to open it on your X display. If that's failing you should get some error message at least

Comment: It is what it returns: Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 9  @boxama

Comment: @AlexanderFill sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735447

Comment: I typed sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8 in komsol but terminalstill doesn't start @boxama

Comment: @AlexanderFill The answers also tell you that a restart is necessary to apply changes. Also, check the contents of `/etc/locale.conf` to check it contains what is expected.